# how to convert NSArray to NSData...or something

Tags: integer, nsarray, nsdata, sparrow-framework

I am rather embarrassed to ask this, but I am on a time limit.  basically, i need to get an array which can hold integers and then those integers can be used to plot a point on an image.

I am trying to make a program where random objects travel down the screen following certain paths, but at random.  So far this is my code:

`enemyPaths = [NSMutableArray array];//5 items (0-4)
  [enemyPaths addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:48]];
  [enemyPaths addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:93]];
  [enemyPaths addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:138]];
  [enemyPaths addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:183]];
  [enemyPaths addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:228]];
  [enemyPaths retain];`

That is the Array. What i want to do is to be able to make a random number generator and have the x point of an object use whatever value comes out of the array as a starting point:

```
double i = (arc4random() % 5);


NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[enemyPaths objectAtIndex: i]];
 image.x = (int)data;
```

I am at a bit of a loss as to what to do, as my knowledge of converting NSarray to NSdata isnt very extensive and this is rather confusing.  I would appreciate any help you can give.

Important note: I am using the Sparrow framework with this program, just so you know.

Comment: Please edit your question so that the line-breaks are correct in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to archive the array in the first place? I think you want to do this:

```
image.x = [[enemyPaths objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Here `intValue` is a method of the `NSNumber` class; it is the inverse of the `numberWithInt` method you used when creating the array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information  I will try it out when I get to work in 8 hours time.
I thought archiving the array would work as that was the only method I had managed to find beforehand.  Unfortunately, i am doing mostly self taught objective-c knowledge (Only started learning a month ago) and it isnt my forte.